# Best way to efficiently send 1000 unique emails using the sendgrid/mail library for Node.JS

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I have an admin panel in my Node.JS application where admins can login and send emails to groups of users. Sometimes these groups can contain up to 1,000 people. When the admin composes an email in the admin panel and hits the send button, I grab each row from the database and generate a unique link for that email body and then send it using the @sendgrid/mail npm package. I have looked at the following page and it is helpful: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/use-cases/README.md#email-use-cases

However, I don't know if it's more efficient to create a giant array of emails and dump that into one of the libraries methods, or if I should loop through and make a separate method call in each iteration and use Promise.all. I suppose I need a solution that won't make the Sendgrid rate limits angry but also not keep my http request loading for 30 seconds for the admin.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the UI you should get all the users that are to be emailed, into the node.js backend app.
In the backend app, assuming you get an array of the users, you use the `Arrays.map()` method to execute a function returns a promise that will send out the email.
You can then use `Promise.all()` to see what emails got send and what failed.
If there are any failures you can show that as a notification to the Admins on the UI, for only those users that failed.

Also note the SendGrid API seems to be capable of accepting 10k requests per second. Do take a look at [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-mail-send-faq/).

Comment: If I use Promise.all() on an array of 1000 promises, does that mean all of those API calls will happen at once? I'm sure my server can't handle that in terms of CPU.

Comment: I don't think the actual email sending will be CPU intensive (but knowing the use case you will be a better judge of that). Most of the time will be spent in IO and that is where node excels.